# Trying to add scrollable tabs in a fragment that extends FragmentActivity, but unable to find the mistake

Tags: android-layout

```
MyEventsFragment.java

List item

    package com.example.edvenswa.collabevents;


    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class MyEventsFragment extends FragmentActivity{

        ViewPager viewPager = null;
        MyAdapter myAdapter;

        public MyEventsFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_my_events);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myEventsPager);

            /*List<Fragment> listFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
            listFragments.add(new MyEventsInsideFragment());
            listFragments.add(new ExpiredEventsFragment());
            listFragments.add(new AttendingEventsFragment());
            listFragments.add(new PastAttendingEventsFragment());*/

            myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myEventsPager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        }



       /* @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_events, container, false);
        }*/


    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Log.d("count","count called"+i);


            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (i == 0) {
                fragment = new MyEventsInsideFragment();
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                fragment = new ExpiredEventsFragment();
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                fragment = new AttendingEventsFragment();
            }
            if (i == 3) {
                fragment = new PastAttendingEventsFragment();
            }

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.d("count", "count called");
            return 4;
        }
    }
```

fragment_my_events.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="com.example.edvenswa.collabevents.MyEvents">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/myEventsPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:gravity="center">



        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



    </FrameLayout>
```

So, this is my code. here I am able to view the first page in fragment but unable scroll and no view of other fragments.

Note: This MyEventsFragment.java is also a fragment in the sidedrawer.

Answer (score 0):

First add the design support library if you haven't

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

then add the [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) like this one.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                 android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Then in your onCreate() method below the viewPager add the following line,

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
 tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Also, in your **FragmentPageAdapter**, you'll have to override **getPageTitle()** method for returning your Tabs title.

Comment: it would be great if you help me out of this issue

Comment: @Vishwanth follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/